# Coverage in WebStorm with Mocha doesn't work

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm, istanbul

I followed this guide to get coverage report integrated in WebStorm.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/mocha.html

When I click "Run Mocha test with coverage" the coverage window shows up after running the test. But I don't see any coverage reported. It is not even showing 0%, it is not showing any numbers at all in the Statistics column.

Any help will be appreciated.

Some more background:

- WebStorm 2017.2.3
- I'm referring Mocha v3.2.0 in package.json
- The code is written in ES2015.
- The mocha Run configuration uses these environment variables

> BABEL_ENV=test and these extra mocha options: --compilers
>   js:babel-core/register

Thanks in advance

Further information: when I run with coverage in WebStorm I see this command being output to the console:

> /Users/nikolaschou/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.2/bin/node /Users/nikolaschou/Dev/dsg/bifrostshop/node_modules/nyc/bin/nyc.js --reporter=lcovonly --extension=.ts --extension=.js --exclude=test/unitmocha/**/*.spec.* --exclude=test/unitmocha/**/*.test.* --report-dir=/private/var/folders/q7/kn0zjzks5dz0q2bx0kpg2yhw0000gn/T/mocha-intellij-coverage- /Users/nikolaschou/Dev/dsg/bifrostshop/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --ui bdd --reporter "/Applications/WebStorm 2.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" --recursive /Users/nikolaschou/Dev/dsg/bifrostshop/test/unitmocha

Comment: what module do you use for collecting coverage - [istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul) or [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc)? Can you collect coverage for your tests when running in cmd line?

Comment: @lena I added more information to my question and as far as I can see, I use nyc

Comment: I have a similar issue.  In my case there is already an **.nycrc** file (to support command-line execution) with
`
"include": [
    "src/"
  ]
`
When I run coverage through WebStorm, I get no coverage (like Nikola).  When I delete (or rename) **.nycrc**, I get coverage on the **test** directory only.

Comment: I have nyc installed and it works fine without this hack.  The only thing I'm not seeing WebStorm do is highlight the lines red or green in the code being covered.  I run my test from a mocha configuration, not command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a file called .nycrc in the project root with these contents:

```
{ "exclude": [] }
```

This overrides `nyc` default config and win is restored.

Comment: Yes thx, it seemed to work. Now I see the coverage percentages.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this problem because mocha did not exit properly. As the coverage reports seem to be generated on program exit, they are never generated.

Mocha 4 especially has changed behaviour from Mocha 3 as it does *"no longer automatically kill itself via process.exit() when it thinks it should be done running"*.

However you can force that old behaviour with the `--exit` option.
The better option is probably to examine what keeps your program from terminating and perform a clean shut down. (Maybe with some help of [wtfnode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode) for example)

**Readings:**

- [Mocha Won't Force Exit](https://boneskull.com/mocha-v4-nears-release/#mochawontforceexit)
- [mocha 4 doesn't exit unlike mocha 3](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3044)